# Share Web (Mac OS X 10.7.4) isn't working

Tags: macos, apache

I have a project developed in php in my Mac Book Pro.

I had never had problems with the Apache server. It always worked fine. It just started normally anytime I switch on the computer.

But now, something has happened that It is not starting normally. Probably due to something I did wrong.

I was following this manual http://www.noppanit.com/apache-enable-mod_rewrite-on-macosx/. Just to turn on the mod_rewrite module.

When I followed this point: `Second go to /private/etc/apache2/user/your-username.conf
Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride all`, I tried to restart the Apache (Share Web) in System preferences, but it just didn't work at all. I click on the Share Web check, but it is not starting.

Any ideas?

Where can I check any log to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. It was just me. For some reason, the `httpd.conf` file had been corrupted and some extra special character had been included at the end causing Apache not to be able to start.

All solved.